# SQL Server Copy from one table to another without using insert into

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to copy a column, `[ExceptionBit]`, from one table to another, but I cannot use `INSERT INTO` because `IDENTITY_INSERT` is set to 'OFF' and I don't have permissions to turn it on. Does anyone know a way of copying from one table to another without having to use `INSERT INTO`?

Here's a snippet of code I'm trying to execute along with the error code:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ReliabilityData].[dbo].[ReferenceDesignator] ON

INSERT INTO [ReliabilityData].[dbo].[ReferenceDesignator] 
        ([ExceptionFlag], [ReferenceDesignatorID]) 
   SELECT [ExceptionFlag], 177375 
   FROM [ReliabilityData].[dbo].[ReferenceDesignator]
   WHERE [ReferenceDesignatorID] = 176839
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:mysql]?

Comment: The error message says something different. It says that either `ReliabilityData.dbo.ReferenceDesignator` does not exist or that you don't have the access rights for it.

Comment: Olivier, it says `[ReliabilityData].[dbo].[ReferenceDesignator]` doesn't exist because I'm trying to turn `IDENTITY_INSERT` to 'ON'. I was showing that setting it to 'ON' was not an option.

Comment: Do you have to use an explicit value for the identity?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check your error message, because that is not about why you are talking in your post, but whatever i tried to find a solution to your 'real' problem, that comment in your post.

I created a cursor, that make a 'fake' insert then, use the @@identity of this insert and then I make an update using identity in where clause.

A cursor is not recommended in most scenaries, if you will use it just for past data one time and in this case is the option that comes to mind.

**Take care with execute this more than 1 time to prevent duplicate data, maybe a join with the destination table it can serve**

```
CREATE TABLE IDENTITY_TABLE
(
  PRIMARY_KEY INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  COL_2 VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE TABLE_2
(
  PRIMARY_KEY INT,
  COL_2 VARCHAR(20)
)


DECLARE @PRIMARY_KEY INT,@COL_2 VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE CURSOR_1 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT PRIMARY_KEY,COL_2 FROM TABLE_2
OPEN CURSOR_1

  FETCH CURSOR_1 
  INTO @PRIMARY_KEY,@COL_2

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO IDENTITY_TABLE
  VALUES ('TEST1')

  PRINT @@IDENTITY

  UPDATE IDENTITY_TABLE
  SET COL_2 = 
  (
   @COL_2
  )
  WHERE PRIMARY_KEY = @@IDENTITY 

     FETCH CURSOR_1
     INTO @PRIMARY_KEY,@COL_2
  END

CLOSE CURSOR_1;
DEALLOCATE CURSOR_1;
```